# android:textAlignment using databinding (TextView)

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to apply android:textAlignment to TextView using databinding like this:

```
 android:textAlignment="@{viewModel.switcher ? START : CENTER}"
```

For now I've implemented it throw gravity:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:gravity="@{viewModel.switcher  ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.CENTER}"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

But can I implement textAlignment directly throw databinding?

Comment: yes you can do that using custom binding adapter.

Answer (score 5):

This works, if you do it like this:

In your databinding layout import View and use it's alignment constants:

```
<layout>

    <data>
         <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        ...
        android:textAlignment="@{View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER}"
        ... />

</layout>
```

You can use the following constants: `View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_INHERIT; View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY; View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START; View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END; View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER; View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START; View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END;`

For more info on these constants check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER).

In your particular case you could write:

```
<layout>

    <data>
         <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
            android:textAlignment="@{viewModel.switcher  ? View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START : View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER}"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

</layout>
```